# CiviMail stuck on 'estimating' number of recipients

Tags: civimail

Drupal 7.69, CiviCRM 5.26.1

Hi everyone,

I had a similar issue (but seem to have identified something different) a few months ago.

Trying to send a mailing to a group, 'Donors'. This group is not a smart group, but it has child groups which are smart groups. I've sent emails to this group many times before. When I select the group, it says no recipients:

[image: When I select the group to mail to]

I then click save draft and re-enter the mailing, and it's stuck on 'Estimating'.

[image: After I save the draft]

This is what I see when I click on the wrench:

[image: Clicking the wrench]

This seems to happen for some groups but not others. I've emailed all these groups in the past.

Flushing the cache did not work. Any ideas on how I can fix this? I really don't want to have to rebuild all the groups all over again, this one in particular has a lot of different sub-groups within it.

Cheers

Comment: Check the system status to see if you have any problems with the criteria of the smart groups. Normally I've seen this error when civi triggers a fatal error while calculating the contacts in SG.

Comment: Next, you can try clicking on the "Update Smart group count" link on manage group page, if it leads to an error, check in the civi log files and try to find which group id was involved during the process.

Comment: @jitendra-fuzion no error in system status or when clicking update smart group. Sorry to clarify (adding this to OP as well), the parent group (which is the one I'm trying to email to) isn't a smart group, but some of its child groups are smart groups.